# fill.gaps() in R does not fill all the gaps in my data

Tags: r

I have a tibble with two columns:

```r
library(tibble)
data <- tibble(yearweek = c("2020 W25", "2020 W33"),
               qty = c(100, 150))
```

I need to add all the week since 2015 W53 until the current week, so I use

```r
data <- data %>%
    fill_gaps(qty = 0,
              .start = yearweek("2016-01-01"),
              .end = yearweek(Sys.time()),
              .full = TRUE)
```

The data produced are not what I need because it still have gaps in the yearweek value (it fills like a week every 8).

What did I miss? Is there any options of the `fill_gaps()` that I miss to do what I want?

EDIT I think the cause of the behaviour is that a clear full index of the yearweek index is missing and the command does not get the full time range. So is there a way to use a full vector of the index value to fill the tibble?

Comment: Which package is `fill.gaps` from?

Comment: Sorry I missed some info of my problem, i edited the question

Answer (score 0):

Adding a W34 to the data results in no gaps.

Adding a W35 to the data results in alternate weeks.

(It seems to be calculating implied missing weeks based on the smallest time-step in the data.)

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tsibble)

# Fill gaps gives consecutive weeks with W34
data <- tibble(
  yearweek = c("2020 W25", "2020 W33", "2020 W34"),
  qty = c(100, 150, 200)
)

data %>%
  mutate(yearweek = yearweek(yearweek)) %>%
  tsibble() %>%
  fill_gaps(
    qty = 0,
    .start = yearweek("2015 W53"),
    .end = yearweek(Sys.time()),
    .full = TRUE
  )
#> Using `yearweek` as index variable.
#> # A tsibble: 341 x 2 [1W]
#>    yearweek   qty
#>      <week> <dbl>
#>  1 2015 W53     0
#>  2 2016 W01     0
#>  3 2016 W02     0
#>  4 2016 W03     0
#>  5 2016 W04     0
#>  6 2016 W05     0
#>  7 2016 W06     0
#>  8 2016 W07     0
#>  9 2016 W08     0
#> 10 2016 W09     0
#> # … with 331 more rows

# Fill gaps gives alternate weeks with W35
data <- tibble(
  yearweek = c("2020 W25", "2020 W33", "2020 W35"),
  qty = c(100, 150, 200)
)

data %>%
  mutate(yearweek = yearweek(yearweek)) %>%
  tsibble() %>%
  fill_gaps(
    qty = 0,
    .start = yearweek("2015 W53"),
    .end = yearweek(Sys.time()),
    .full = TRUE
  )
#> Using `yearweek` as index variable.
#> # A tsibble: 174 x 2 [2W]
#>    yearweek   qty
#>      <week> <dbl>
#>  1 2015 W53     0
#>  2 2016 W02     0
#>  3 2016 W04     0
#>  4 2016 W06     0
#>  5 2016 W08     0
#>  6 2016 W10     0
#>  7 2016 W12     0
#>  8 2016 W14     0
#>  9 2016 W16     0
#> 10 2016 W18     0
#> # … with 164 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>